# Using multiple models as one

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I want to have one model that can be customised with different parts eg. Different arm models or different head models. I want them to all be different models (one for the head, body, one for each arm and one for each leg) and then have them all pieced together and rendered to look like one complete model. How could I implement this into my project using lwjgl and OpenGL?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't simply load multiple separate models around the same location? For example, if a player in my game has captured a flag, I simply render a separate flag model, I don't somehow merge the flag model with the player model (although it *is* possible).

Comment: @Joehot200 I just want to do it really so I don't have to make all the individual models. I could just use a combination of different parts of models. I guess making each individual model is one of the most sensible options though

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways that I could think of that would work, some of them touching on the concept of [Skeletal Animation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeletal_animation).

First, you could use your modeling software (for example, blender) and add all of the components into the scene individually, then just read in the whole scene into your game.

Another way of going about this would be to try to give each component the role of a bone, then use a skeleton structure to link all the bones together. The only problem with this is that you're going to have to create your own variables for the skinning formula.

Lastly, you could load them all into a scene in your modeling software, link them with joints, then export that into your game. This would be my choice since it would give you all the information you need to perform the skinning formula, which will give you the ability to animate the components of your structure.